# proper way to pass data from registerForActivityResult to onCreate method

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the onCreate method:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ...
        ...
srButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
    
   
 chooseImageGallery()

    if (theSelectedImage == null) {
      ....}
 
    val bitmap = (theSelectedImage.drawable as BitmapDrawable)?.bitmap
}

      
private fun chooseImageGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"

        //setContentView(R.layout.selected_image) // DELETE THIS

        theSelectedImage = findViewById(R.id.the_selected_image)
        getResultCamera2.launch(intent)
```

}

```
private val getResultCamera2 =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                theSelectedImage.setImageURI(it.data?.data)
          

            }
        }
```

I want, to press the button and select an image from gallery. And show that image.
With the above code I can do that.

But the problem is with the  `if (theSelectedImage == null)`. The `theSelectedImage` is null because it isn't updated in the onCreate method.

How can I update that?

Note, that I used:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.selected_image)
 theSelectedImage = findViewById(R.id.the_selected_image)
```

inside the `chooseImageGallery` in order to be able to initialize these.

So, what is a proper way to do that?

**UPDATE**

I deleted the `setContentView(R.layout.selected_image)`. It seems I forgot this from another thing.

Now, `theSelectedImage` is not null , but when I call

`val bitmap = (theSelectedImage.drawable as BitmapDrawable)?.bitmap`

it gives :

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`

Also, is there a better way to handle those data transfers to the `onCreate` method?

Comment: Why do you have two `setContentView()` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand your issue, and I'd let you know what is going wrong right now and what a better solution would be.

**What's wrong right now?**

Your idea is correct, implementation is a bit wrong.

```kotlin
if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           theSelectedImage.setImageURI(it.data?.data)
     }
```

This is correct, what you need to understand here is `it.data?.data` is an optional call you're making so this value can be `null`.

So when you try to this later, it throws an error

```kotlin
val bitmap = (theSelectedImage.drawable as BitmapDrawable)?.bitmap
```

Modify this to the follow

```kotlin
val bitmap = (theSelectedImage.drawable as? BitmapDrawable)?.bitmap
```

We have made it an optional cast now, so that should fix your error at least.

**Recommendations**

I'd recommend to make a separate function entirely to call and handle your result

```
fun handleImageResponse(intent: Intent?) {
// Do stuff here
}
```

And call this like this

```kotlin
if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           handleImageResponse(it.data)
     }
```